# Cannot find a version of 'androidx.arch.core:core-common' that satisfies the version constraints

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, androidx

With a new Android Studio project created (Empty Activity type), if you add the following lines:

```
    // Lifecycle/View Models
    def lifecycleVersion = '2.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycleVersion"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycleVersion"

    // Core testing
    def coreTestingVersion = '2.0.1'
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$coreTestingVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$coreTestingVersion"
```

To the app's `build.gradle` file you will see errors when you try to run the `connectedCheck` task for the project.  See output:

```
Zachs-MBP:CoreTestingVersionExample Zach$ ./gradlew connectedCheck

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.arch.core:core-common' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0'
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.1' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.1'
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0'
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.1.0-alpha03' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0'
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0'
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha03' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0-alpha05' --> 'androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0-alpha05' --> 'androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.0.0-alpha02' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0'
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0

   > Could not resolve androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.1' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1'
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0'
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0'
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0'
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0

   > Could not resolve androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app > androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.1
      > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.1' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1'
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0'
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0'
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0'
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0

   > Could not resolve androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0
         project :app > androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0
         project :app > androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.1.0-alpha03
         project :app > androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0
         project :app > androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.0.0-alpha02
      > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.arch.core:core-common' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0'
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.1' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.1'
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0'
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.1.0-alpha03' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0'
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0'
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha03' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0-alpha05' --> 'androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0-alpha05' --> 'androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.0.0-alpha02' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0'
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0

   > Could not resolve androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0
         project :app > androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0
         project :app > androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0
      > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.1' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1'
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0'
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0'
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0'
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0

   > Could not resolve androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app > androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1
      > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.arch.core:core-common' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0'
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.1' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.1'
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0'
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.1.0-alpha03' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0'
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0'
           Dependency path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha03' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0-alpha05' --> 'androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0-alpha05' --> 'androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.0.0-alpha02' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0'
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Constraint path 'CoreTestingVersionExample:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-common' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

If I use the same `lifecycleVersion` and `coreTestingVersion` value (2.0.0 for example) the errors do not occur, but lint complains that the core testing dependencies have an updated version (2.0.1). (At least it runs, though :P)  I thought one of the advantages of `androidx` was that it would allow for updating individual pieces without issue?

Here's a sample app showing the issue: https://github.com/ZOlbrys/CoreTestingVersionExample

Simply run `connectedCheck` via terminal in this project to see the build fail.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

edit: created google issue for this, see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129316035

Comment: did you try invalidate cache and restart?

Comment: Yes! I've also done a full reboot of the computer, and checked on two different computers, but the issue still exists.

Comment: try checking if your offline work is enabled or disabled ..in android studio

Comment: offline work is disabled in my settings.

Comment: I created an Android issue for this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129316035

Comment: @Zach did you ever find a solution to this issue: I am facing a similar issue as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55570829/cannot-find-version-of-androidx-arch-androidx-room-etc?noredirect=1#comment97846812_55570829

Answer (score 11):

To resolve this issue you will have to use a dependency resolution strategy. This is how I resolved it when I faced a similar issue: [Cannot find version of 'androidx.arch', 'androidx.room', etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55570829/cannot-find-version-of-androidx-arch-androidx-room-etc?noredirect=1#comment97846812_55570829)

```
configurations.all
            {
                resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                    if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.arch.core'
                            && !details.requested.name.contains('core-runtime')) {
                        details.useVersion "2.0.1"
                    }

}
```

Fyi for each dependency is represented as implementation "**group*:*name*:*version**"

Comment: This seems to work so far - I'll investigate some more, and will post in the google issue as well if I don't see anything wrong with this...  Thanks!

Comment: I would also advice moving to move to use Kotlin DSL in your dependencies

Comment: This did not work for my situation, where did you add it?

Comment: Where do we need to  put this in gradle?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do two workarounds to fix this issue:

1. Use the latest google play services library: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin
2. As mentioned in other answers:

   ```
     configurations.all
               {
                   resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                       if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.arch.core'
                               && !details.requested.name.contains('core-runtime')) {
                           details.useVersion "2.0.1"
                       }

   }
   ```

Comment: where did you add that? on the dependencies?

Comment: @MadonaSyombua Yes. inside dependencies { } block.Make sure you have the latest Google play services library too. Source issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129316035